# Removing global app reference from blueprint in Flask

Tags: python, flask, routes

I'm currently working on learning Flask and create a working page with login functions. Now I want to remove the global app instance and started using blueprints for the submodules.

My project is structured like this:

```
+ app
    + auth
        - __init__.py
        - forms.py
        - routes.py
    + main
    + models
    + templates
    - __init__.py
+ migrations
- index.py
- config.py
```

No I added a blueprint to the `routes.py` and used the decorators there:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, Blueprint
from app import app, db
from app.auth.forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
# ...
from app.models.User import User

blueprint = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return "example login"
```

The `__init__.py` of the auth module:

```
from . import forms, routes
```

The blueprint gets added in the `__init__.py` of the app folder:

```
# ...
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from app.auth.routes import blueprint as auth_bp
app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
```

After using the @blueprint decorators, I don't need @app anymore, but how can I access the db when I want to remove the `import app` and the `from app.models.User import User` part?

Answer (score 0):

```
from . import db
```

```
from ..models.User import User
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to understand here. `app` as a module (the folder) and `app` the instance of flask inside `__init__.py`. When you do `import app` inside authentication blueprint then you are actually importing the whole `app` module and not the flask instance. When you do `from app import app` you are actually importing flask instance from `app` module. This can be confusing to eliminate this I advise you to change the name of `app` folder to something different like `bacher` then when you need to import `db` inside your authentication blueprint use `from bacher import db` and for `User` model `from bacher.models.User import User`